# How to use PHP variable value in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm using PHP, HTML and Javascript for my web app.
Now I'm having a small issue with the following code.

```
$e=$_POST['users']; //$e should have either employee_id or a string "All"
```

Now depending on this value I've to redirect a HTML button to a specific page.
In my case

```
if $e=="employee_id(or may be you could say that $e!="All")" then redirect the page to salary_report.php
```

and `if $e=="All" then the page should redirect to salary_report_combined.php`

My current button code is as follows :

```
<input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="leavere" name="leavere" value="Back to Salary Report" onclick="location.replace('salary_report.php')"></input>
```

So currently it is redirecting to salary_report.php file only. My issue is how should I apply a condition based on PHP variable value and execute the HTML code? Now could you help me in resolveing ithis issue. Thnks in advance.

Comment: I'd just make a link and make it look like a button and print the `href` with PHP based on your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if($e == "All"){
$redirectTo = "salary_report_combined.php";
}
else{
$redirectTo = "salary_report.php";
}
```

In your button:

```
<input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="leavere" name="leavere" 
value="Back to Salary Report" onclick="location.replace('<?php echo $redirectTo ?>')"></input>
```

But I'd just create a link with the redirect page as `href`, like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo $redirectTo; ?>"> Back to Salary Report </a>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use as below:

```
var $e = <?php echo $_POST['users'] ?>;
```

then use **$e** in condition.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to your problem you can store redirection url into a php variable and then access the value of php variable within javascript code snippet.

E.g

```
 <?php
 $redirection_url='';   //Initialzing of variable for redirection url
 if($e=='All')
 {
     $redirection_url='salery_report_combined.php';
 }
 else
 {
      $redirection_url='salary_report.php';
 }
 ?>

    <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="leavere" name="leavere" value="Back to Salary Report" onclick="window.location.replace('<?php echo $redirection_url; ?>')"></input>
```